# Working of MRI in detection of tissues for imaging

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, magnetic-moment, protons, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

why we consider the rotational axis of proton under the action of magnetic field in MRI not electron?

Answer (score 3):

We certainly could consider electrons using a similar approach as with MRI. This is called [Electron Paramagnetic Resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_paramagnetic_resonance) (EPR). The main difference is the resonance frequency. At a given field strength the EPR frequency is much higher than the NMR frequency.

EPR is not used clinically for the following reasons:

1. The frequencies are in the microwave range so they produce a lot of heat
2. The abundance of unpaired electrons is lower than the abundance of hydrogen nuclei
3. The diagnostic utility is far less well studied